# Каким образом можно автоматически генерировать field(поле) в документе? или автоматически генерировать поля в переменной с типом map?

Tags: firebase

[image]

ну вот что бы я добавлял данные и у меня автоматически создавались либо поле 3, либо в переменную g с типом map тоже добавлялось поле 3

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хочу заносить данные в поля, но мне нужно заносить данные не в уже созданные поля, а в новые, так что бы они сами генерировались и в сгенерированные поля я заносил данные. И я вот не знаю каким образом можно сгенерировать новые поля. я знаю что id  генерируются с помощью add(), а поля каким образом генерируются без понятия